# RDF: when a property is used the thing in the object position is a literal of datatype X

Tags: rdf, owl, jena, rdfs

In quite a few ontologies we have triples like this:

```
gist:containedText
    a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
    rdfs:range xsd:string ;
```

What they *intend* to express is that if you use that property (gist:containedText) the thing in the object position is a literal of datatype xsd:string.

e.g. This is a triple that conforms to that *intention*:

```
:thing0 gist:containedText "this is my text"^^xsd:string .
# "this is my text" is a literal of datatype xsd:string
```

I think several answers get this wrong by recommending `rdfs:range`:

[In an ontology, how to define a property's value as a datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486301/in-an-ontology-how-to-define-a-propertys-value-as-a-datetime/21490116#21490116)

[RDF : Is it possible to set the range of a property to a literal in Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235086/rdf-is-it-possible-to-set-the-range-of-a-property-to-a-literal-in-turtle)

[The simplest way of declaring that a property’s range is one of a limited number of literal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180674/the-simplest-way-of-declaring-that-a-property-s-range-is-one-of-a-limited-number)

**But** rdfs:range isn't about the datatype of literals -- it is about instances of classes.

Look what an rdfs reasoner produces if you give it those triples as input:

```
apache-jena-5.0.0/bin/riot --formatted=turtle --rdfs=tbox.ttl abox.ttl 
<snip>
"this is my text"  rdf:type  xsd:string .
:thing0  gist:containedText  "this is my text" .
```

And notice that is not well-formed RDF (there is a literal in the subject position).

And we don't mean that "this is my text" is an instance of the class `xsd:string`.

Apache Jena confirms that the RDF is not well-formed:

```
apache-jena-5.0.0/bin/riot --rdfs=tbox.ttl abox.ttl | apache-jena-5.0.0/bin/riot --validate --syntax=turtle -
16:34:29 ERROR riot            :: [line: 2, col: 69] Subject is not a URI or blank node
```

The question is then: in RDF, how do we express if you use property Y the thing in the object position is a literal of datatype X?

Comment: More discussion is here:
https://github.com/semanticarts/gist/issues/1069

Comment: The triplets are OWL inferences not RDF triples. There's an overlap but the are not the same thing. rdfs:range applied to data properties is for expressing datatypes, i.ee., exactly how it's used in your example ontology.

Answer (score 3):

You should keep using `rdfs:range` in this way, it has the intended meaning under both RDFS and [OWL2-DL semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/). Jena should be filtering out triples that have have literals in the subject position. As @IS4 states, this is just syntax, and there are proposals to relax that restriction, [approved by Tim Berners-Lee](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/semantic-web/2018Nov/0058.html).

Things get more complicated when you start mixing `owl:DatatypeProperty` and `owl:ObjectProperty`, [not permitted in OWL2-DL](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning), but allowed in OWL-Full. However, in the case you provide, `gist:containedText` is syntactically constrained to be a `owl:DatatypeProperty` in OWL2-DL, and the semantics of range are as you intend. You can check this by substituting `xsd:string` for `xsd:integer`, and OWL-DL reasoners such as HermiT will tell you the ontology plus ABox is inconsistent. Don't be misled by Jena's confusing behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You are conflating *syntax* with *semantics*. OWL (and RDF Schema) gives an *interpretation* to RDF terms, but such an interpretation does not necessarily have to be encodable in RDF.

> What they *intend* to express is that if you use that property (gist:containedText) the thing in the object position is a literal of datatype xsd:string.

I can't speak for the authors of the ontologies, but OWL gives a clear definition of what this expresses: that the individual identified by the literal has to be an instance of `xsd:string`.

You are right that this does not say anything about the literal itself ‒ `:thing0 gist:containedText "en"^^xsd:language` is *also* valid according to the ontology, because `xsd:language rdfs:subClassOf xsd:string`.

> **But** rdfs:range isn't about the datatype of literals -- it is about instances of classes.

Correct. *But* a literal is not an object an OWL reasoner works with ‒ it is a term in RDF whose interpretation is an instance of `rdfs:Literal` ‒ a *literal value*. OWL reasoning does not operate on RDF terms, it operates on classes, properties, and individuals (with the exception of `owl:DatatypeProperty` which is meaningless in OWL Full anyway).

> ```
> "this is my text"  rdf:type  xsd:string .
> :thing0  gist:containedText  "this is my text" .
> ```
>
> And notice that is not well-formed RDF (there is a literal in the subject position).

It is not syntactically valid (though it may certainly be one day) but that is irrelevant ‒ it is obvious what this means. That being said, it is not even necessary to emit `"this is my text" rdf:type xsd:string .` as that is already true even without using the property.

You could also fix the syntax issue very easily with `owl:sameAs`:

```
:thing0 gist:containedText _:literal .
_:literal a xsd:string ; owl:sameAs "this is my text" .
```

This is exactly the same thing, but well-formed and valid.

> And we don't mean that "this is my text" is an instance of the class `xsd:string`.

Who exactly? Feel free to pick a different alternative if OWL/RDF Schema is not compatible with what you yourself need to express. SHACL, for example, operates on a lower level and should be able to constrain the datatype precisely, not as an individual. Otherwise you have to accept that (in RDF Schema and OWL Full) all of these graphs are also valid and in accordance with the ontology:

```
:thing0 gist:containedText [] .
```

```
:thing0 gist:containedText <http://example.com/> .
```

```
:thing0 gist:containedText [
  a rdfs:Literal
] .
```

```
:thing0 gist:containedText [
  a xsd:string
] .
```

```
:thing0 gist:containedText [
  a xsd:language
] .
```

While this is not:

```
:thing0 gist:containedText 1 .
```

---

I believe OWL actually works well in this situation ‒ when you express that a property links a thing to a string, this is *exactly* how you should express it, with `rdfs:domain` and `rdfs:range`, but it also gives you a bit of very convenient leeway *not* to identify the literal directly, as it doesn't tell you anything about how the property is actually supposed to be used. That is what an ontology should do, it should give meaning to the terms you use, not restrict how you should use them. That is the job of a system that accepts RDF graphs, which may well restrict it to a subset of what an ontology permits.

You can also do some pretty nice things with the way OWL works, like this:

```
:thing0 gist:containedText _:unknown .
:thing1 gist:containedText _:unknown .
```

You can express naturally that two things contain the same text without stating what that text is, which you couldn't do if you constrained the form and not the essence.

Comment: > That being said, it is not even necessary to emit "this is my text" rdf:type xsd:string . as that is already true even without using the property.

I think that is wrong -- it can't be a true because it isn't valid.

An RDF triple consists of three components:

the subject, which is an IRI or a blank node

...

https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#conformance

The subject of that triples is not an IRI or a blank node.

Comment: @justin2004 Your reasoning is still incorrectly based on conflating syntax and semantics, as I attempt to explain in the rest of the answer. You link to a rule about *triples*, but reasoners output *facts*. A fact may be expressed as a triple (or collection thereof), but in this case the triple happens to be invalid. But the fact is still sound. Check out https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdf_entailment_patterns ‒ you can see there that you can describe a literal value without using a literal, and it is precisely how other individuals are described.

Comment: If the entailed triples are invalid then what does that say about the triples that the entailed triples are derived from?

Comment: @justin2004 Nothing.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. I look forward to responses from others.

Comment: @justin2004 I am afraid I cannot explain it more than by repeating what I have said already. It simply doesn't matter that the fact inferred by a reasoner is not expressible directly as a triple. The fact is still clear: `"this is my text"` is a string. How could it not be?

Comment: @IS4 You claim "a literal is not an object an OWL reasoner works with". What is your reference for this? Literals are part of the [direct model-theoretic semantics for OWL 2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-direct-semantics/), and there are many OWL-DL reasoners that implement this.

Comment: @ChrisMungall Maybe I was a bit vague for the sake of argument here ‒ OWL definitely does define what a literal is and how to interpret it, since it needs to understand the mapping between the lexical and value space of the datatype. I was just referring to how entailment should really operate on the value space, not the lexical space ‒ `"1"^^xsd:byte`, `"1"^^xsd:integer`, `"1.0"^^xsd:decimal` are all *the same thing* for the purpose of reasoning, because they identify the same object in the literal value space.

Comment: I was also using the terminology from RDF Schema, whereby a *literal value* is the resource that is the actual instance of `rdfs:Literal`, and a *literal* is the term it was constructed from.